# Loading an external file on startup

Tags: vb.net, excel

I have only started learning VB but I have a question. I have created a form that reads data from an Excel spreadsheet and populates comboboxes, but I have linked the code to a button press. I don't know if it can be done, but is there anyway I can automate this process to be done when i first load up the form, without the need for user input.

i.e
Start up program
Program loads
loads excel sheet
populates combobox
program ready to be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is move the code you have for the Button into the `Form_load` event.

Take a look at this Article: http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/NET/nets10p4.html

**Form Load**

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    'This will fire everytime the Form1 is Loaded.
}
```

**Form Close**

```
private void Form1_Closed(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    'This will fire everytime the Form1 is closed.
}
```

Events are very powerful, get accustom to them ;)

Here's another great resource to study basics the of Events http://www.tutorialspoint.com/vb.net/vb.net_event_handling.htm

Comment: Thanks! Should have realised that if the buttons, boxes etc. have listed events, then the actual form would too.